# Word for an amount of money that is possible to pay but is not reasonable

Tags: word-request

Suppose that paying k$ for something (e.g., a house) is possible for me (I have that amount of money), but considering other factors (e.g., I may be able to spend it in a better way), I think it is not reasonable to pay that. Assume that the price is not high, but when considering all factors, I think that spending that amount of money somewhere else may be a better decision

If I say that "It is not possible for me to pay it", the listener may think that I do not have that amount of money.

How can I say such a sentence so that the reader knows that I think paying that money is not reasonable for me? Can I use the word reasonable itself: "It is not reasonable for me to pay it"? Is there a better word?

Comment: I'd say that the price is not reasonable, not that it is not reasonable for/of sb to pay it.

Comment: Assume that I'm not bargaining and the price is fixed, but it is not reasonable for me to pay it. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my original answer, since it seems that I misunderstood your question.

**Unreasonable** by itself is probably not precise enough since it fails to differentiate between situations where the price is intrinsically unreasonable (no one should be expected to pay that price) and ones where it's unreasonable for you to make this purchase at this time (because there are wiser uses of your money). In fact, this ambiguity is what led me to misunderstand your question.

If the price is intrinsically unreasonable, then the price is [**exorbitant**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exorbitant).

If the price is reasonable, but it's unreasonable for you to make this purchase at this time, then here are a couple of options:

The purchase is [**frivolous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frivolous) or the item is a **frivolity**. This would not often be used for an expensive item like a house, unless you are rich enough that buying the house has very little impact on your financial security. It is more often used for smaller purchases like new clothing that you don't actually need.

Making the purchase could be [**imprudent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imprudent) (or "not prudent"), meaning lacking in good judgment.  That is, the price might be a fair price for the purchase, but it shows lack of judgment for you to make this purchase.  For example:

> I love that house that's for sale down the street. I could certainly afford it, but it would be **imprudent** for me to buy it now when I should be saving up for my children's college education.

Comment: The price is not exorbitant. When considering all factors, I may think that spending that amount of money somewhere else may be a better decision.

Comment: So am I understanding that you're saying that the price is a **reasonable** price, but it's your choice to spend the money in this way that's unreasonable?

Comment: I may have better choices. So if I choose this choice (paying that amount of money for that thing), I have done something unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as if you're not saying that the amount of *money* is unreasonable, rather that making the choice to spend your money on it would not be [**wise**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/wise):

> **1 a** : characterized by wisdom : marked by deep understanding, keen discernment, and a capacity for sound judgment
>   **b** : exercising or showing sound judgment : PRUDENT
>   // a *wise* investor

Or, in reverse, it would be an *unwise* choice.

Answer (score 0):

Typical expressions for this situations refer to the offer rather than just the amount of money.

You can say "it's not worth that much" (or as Mr. Trump would put it: it's a bad deal).

A stronger colloquial expression is "it's a ripoff".